# Исключение: Column "id" not found

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

при попытки QUERY запроса в БД сыпется ошибка о том, что колонка не найдена, хотя все колонки прописаны и в самой БД этот запрос работает корректно.

Запрос в БД (149 было взято для проверки запроса) :

```
SELECT cargo.cargo_number as name
FROM cargo 
INNER JOIN cargo_inbound_trucks on (cargo.id = cargo_inbound_trucks.cargos_id)
LEFT JOIN inboundtruck ON inboundtruck.id = cargo_inbound_trucks.inbound_trucks_id WHERE inboundtruck.id = 149
```

Repository:

```
public interface InboundTruckRepository extends JpaRepository<InboundTruck, Long> {


@Query(value = "SELECT cargo.cargo_number as cargoNumber, cargo.status as Status " +
        "FROM cargo " +
        "INNER JOIN cargo_inbound_trucks on (cargo.id = cargo_inbound_trucks.cargos_id)" +
        "LEFT JOIN InboundTruck ON InboundTruck.id = cargo_inbound_trucks.inbound_trucks_id WHERE InboundTruck.ID = :id", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<InboundTruck> findCargoByID(@Param("id") Long id);

}
```

Таблицы в БД:

Cargo:
[image: Cargo]
cargo_inbound_trucks:

[image: cargo_inbound_trucks]

inboundtruck:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кусок ошибки в консоли:

```
    2020-05-18 16:24:48.596  WARN 23944 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2020-05-18 16:24:48.596 ERROR 23944 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'id' not found.
2020-05-18 16:24:48.615 ERROR 23944 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:548) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:818) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:808) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:732) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1008) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2131) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1530) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1578) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла замена выбранных столбцов на "*"

```
public interface InboundTruckRepository extends JpaRepository<InboundTruck, Long> {


@Query(value = "SELECT * " +
        "FROM cargo " +
        "INNER JOIN cargo_inbound_trucks on (cargo.id = cargo_inbound_trucks.cargos_id)" +
        "LEFT JOIN InboundTruck ON InboundTruck.id = cargo_inbound_trucks.inbound_trucks_id WHERE InboundTruck.ID = :id", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<InboundTruck> findCargoByID(@Param("id") Long id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT cargo.cargo_number as cargoNumber, cargo.status as Status " +
        "FROM cargo " +
        "INNER JOIN cargo_inbound_trucks on (cargo.id = cargo_inbound_trucks.cargos_id)" +
        "LEFT JOIN InboundTruck ON InboundTruck.id = cargo_inbound_trucks.inbound_trucks_id WHERE InboundTruck.ID = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<InboundTruck> findCargoByID(@Param("id") Long id);

}
```

Comment: забыл добавить это в пост, извините, ошибка с данным параметром на месте